# Interacting with Unity UI using daydream controller as a pointer

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

I am aware of GazeInputModule, which allows users to interact with Unity's UI system using head movement. I was wondering if there is a possibility to use Daydream's controller as a pointer to interact with user interface instead. Any tips or advices are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In latest GVR Unity SDK, there are sample scenes for daydream. Check them out as they are using GVRController for interaction. I assume that you are using latest [Unity Daydream Preview](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream) which has built-in support for GVR. So here are the steps to follow:

**1. Add GVRPointerInputModule to EventSystem :**

[image]

**2. Add following Prefabs in your scene:**

[image]

**3. Attach GVRPointerGraphicRaycaster to world space canvas and set MainCamera as event camera in canvas component:**

[image]

**4. And finally make sure to add enable virtual reality support from player settings and add Daydream SDK:**

[image]

Note: Remove old components like GazeInputModule, GraphicRaycaster etc.

**Additional:**

You can change Controller's Arm model as preferred(Currently it has options of Pointer, Wrist, Elbow and Shoulder)

[image]

I hope this helps.